# How to post form using angular js 4

Tags: forms, angular, post

I am creating single page application with angular js 4.

How can I post form on submit button click using angular js 4.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply get your form value using this and post to the database or wherever you want.

```
this.formName.value
```

for more detail see demo example by angular

- https://embed.plnkr.co/?show=preview